# Can I connect to Wifi after flashing GSI

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader, android-10, mac-address, treble

My old phone is running Android 10. I wanted to install Android 14 beta on it. Bootloader is locked.

From what I know, unlocking bootloader would reset the device. Therefore Wifi passwords are gone. This is ok as I know them. The problem is my router admin has setup something so when using randomized MAC address it doesn't connect. But fron what I Googled, it seems MAC address is hardware based so resetting phone wouldn't change it.

So, my question is, does MAC address reset in unlocking bootloader or flashing GSI make me unable to access the network? If possible, please actually try because I don't want to mess up I have no experience in this area.

Comment: That depends. There is one randomization mode that generates for each Wifi an own MAC address (for that Wifi the MAC is then always the same). The algorithm that generates the MAC address bases (as far as I remember) internally on a secret that is user specific, thus will be erased on factory reset. If the Wifi connection you currently use is configured to use such a generated (but Wifi static) MAC address, it will also be erased by a factory reset. Next time you try to connect after factory reset the MAC would be different.

Comment: If i choose "use device MAC" instead of "random MAC", stuff should work right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed myself by unlocking BL, flashing ODIN with magisk patch. Still same MAC address